# How can I get `reduce` to divide values in the stream by one another?

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

I have a stream of Integers and the source of the stream is a list: `[3, 27]`.

When doing `list.stream.reduce(1, (a,b) -> a/b))`, how do I get the reduce to divide 3/1 = 3 then 27/3 = 9 and return 9?

Answer (score 7):

One should not use `reduce` with an accumulator function that is not [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity). This has been especially highlighted in the JDK [documentation of the API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) as well.

> The accumulator function *must be an associative* function.

You don't really need to rely on streams for this manipulation, in fact, streams are not good in persisting intermediate states(as in this case), so a simple for loop solution shall work for you :

```
int reduce = 1;
for (Integer integer : List.of(3, 27)) {
    reduce = integer / reduce;
}
System.out.println(reduce);
```

To test out the inconsistency in terms of using the stream API for this purpose, just change your code to the following and notice the output!

```
Integer reduce = List.of(3, 7).parallelStream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> b / a);
System.out.println(reduce);
```

Comment: Note that `27/(3/1) == 27 * (3 * 1^(-1))^(-1) == 27 * 3^(-1) * 1` -- you get an alternating product, which _is_ associative. Now I just have to find out how to implement `zipWith` in Java :) (Which IIRC doesn't exist...)

Answer (score 2):

You have to swap a and b:

```
System.out.println (Stream.of(3,27).reduce(1, (a,b) -> b/a));
```

output:

```
9
```

Comment: One shall expect a mention to *The accumulator function must be an **associative** function.*